# remove br tag if data empty or null in laravel blade view

Tags: php, laravel

i show data in blade view like this :

```
 @foreach($data as $dt)
<tr>
<td>
{{Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_1,'nama','id')}} <br>
{{Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_2,'nama','id')}} <br>
{{Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_3,'nama','id')}} <br>
{{Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_4,'nama','id')}} <br>
{{Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_5,'nama','id')}} <br>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

table look like :

```
No | Pihak

1    Muhammad Abdul Iradat
     Muhammad Abdul Iradat
     Muhammad Abdul Iradat
     Muhammad Abdul Iradat
```

but when one of data empty or null table show :

(example if data 'pihak_4' empty)

```
No | Pihak

1    Muhammad Abdul Iradat
     Muhammad Abdul Iradat
     Muhammad Abdul Iradat

     Muhammad Abdul Iradat
```

how to remove br tag if data empty?

i use this but i don't know how to remove br tag if data empty

```
 {{ !empty(Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_2,'nama','id')) ? Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_2,'nama','id') :'' }}
```

index controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $title = $this->title;
    $data = DB::select('SELECT * ,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(tgl_selesai, CURDATE()) <= 0 THEN "Berakhir"
        WHEN DATEDIFF(tgl_selesai, CURDATE()) < 30  THEN "Akan Berakhir"
        ELSE "Masih Berjalan"
        END status
        FROM kesepakatan_bersamas');
    return view('admin.'.$title.'.index', compact('title','data'));
}
```

Comment: what did you try before coming to SO?

Comment: i use  {{ !empty(Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_2,'nama','id')) ? Helper::getDetail('mitras', $dt->pihak_2,'nama','id') :'' }} but i don't know how to remove br tag

Comment: add code into Q ^ :)

Answer (score 1):

I would change your Helper::getDetail to be able to take an array as the second value. I would strip out this logic as it shouldn't really be in your view file, and instead put it in your controller.

This way you can call your helper in your controller:

```
$yourValues = [$dt->pihak_1, $dt->pihak_2 ...];
$details = Helper::getDetail('mitras', $yourValues,'nama','id');
```

This way, you are calling the function once, instead of several times over in your view, which can be inefficient.

You would then pass `$details` into your view, and inside your view do:

```
<td>
    @foreach($details as $detail)
        @if($detail) // checks if null value
            {{ $detail }} <br>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</td>
```

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: i call helper in controller but  get error message  "Trying to get property of non-object ". i have update my question

Comment: Did you change the second parameter of `getDetail` to be able to take an array and make the relevant changes to allow for it?

Comment: i use this ` $yourValues = [$data->pihak_2,$data->pihak_3,$data->pihak_4];
$details = Helper::getDetail('mitras', $yourValues,'nama','id');`

Comment: Yes, but you need to change Helper::getDetail so that it can take an array... like the function getDetail needs to be changed.